# How can i write the formula of a (power function) in (properties window ) of a variable in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I'm making a system dynamic model and i want to make a graph between cumulative(NPV)and time, but the value of it is (NPV=(Income-costs)/(1+r)^t), i tried sign (^), power, pow, math.pow and exp in (properties window) of the variable but they were useless, always show an error ("syntax error")

Comment: Do show a screenshot of the actual code, likely just a typo. Also, did you use code-complete? (Ctrl-space)

Comment: <img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/13lo6e8StKuDfkvC749lb1Ih3tvliVdrF/view?usp=sharing"> i just entered this formula in the picture and showed this error in java source

Comment: and did you check the syntax? Could just be a typo, did you use code-complete and are you sure there is no typo?

Answer (score 0):

you are basically missing a parenthesis in your code

YOu have

```
((Income/LLC)/something
```

DO you see where the problem is? The first parenthesis shouldn't be there